# Z3 vZ - Adding constraint improves optimum

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm new to using Z3 and am trying to model an ILP, which I have already successfully done using the MILP Solver PuLP. I now implemented the same objective function (which is to be minimized) and the same constraints in Z3 and am experiencing strange behaviour. Mainly, that adding a constraint decreases the minimum.

**My question is:** How can that be? Is it a bug or can it be explained somehow?

---

More detail, in case needed:

I'm trying to solve a Teacher Assignment Problem. Courses are scheduled before a year and the teachers get the list of the courses. They then can select which courses they want to teach, with which priority they want to teach it, how many workdays (each course lasts several days) they desire to teach and a max and min number of courses they definitly want to teach. The program gets as input a list of possible teacher-assignments. A teacher-assignment is a tuple consisting of:

1. teacher-name
2. event-id
3. priority of teacher towards event
4. the distance between teacher and course

**The goal** of the program to find a combination of assignments that minimize:

1. the average relative deviation 'desired workdays <-> assigned workdays' of all teachers
2. the maximum relative deviation 'desired workdays <-> assigned workdays' of any teacher
3. the overall distance of courses to assigned teachers
4. the sum of priorities (higher priority means less willingness to teach)

**Main Constraints:**

1. number of teachers assigned to course must match needed amount of teachers
2. the number of assigned courses to a teacher must be within the specified min/max range
3. the courses to which a teacher is assigned may not overlap in time (a list of overlap-sets are given)

To track the average relative deviation and the maximum deviation of workdays two more **'helper-constraints'** are introduced:

4. for each teacher: overload (delta_plus) - underload (delta_minus) = assigned workdays - desired workdays
5. for each teacher: delta_plus + delta_minus <= max relative deviation (DELTA)

Here you have this as Python code:

```py
from z3 import *

def compute_optimum(a1, a2, a3, a4, worst_case_distance=0):
    """
    Find the optimum solution with weights a1, a2, a3, a4
    (average workday deviation, maximum workday deviation, cummulative linear distance, sum of priority 2 assignments)
    Higher weight = More optimized (value minimized)

    Returns all assignment-tuples which occur in the calculated optimal model.
    """

    print("Powered by Z3")
    print(f"\n\n\n\n ------- FINDING OPTIMUM TO WEIGHTS: a1={a1}, a2={a2}, a3={a3}, a4={a4} -------\n")
    
    # key: assignment tuple     value: z3-Bool
    x = {assignment : Bool('e%i_%s' % (assignment[1], assignment[0])) for assignment in possible_assignments}

    delta_plus = {teacher : Int('d+_%s' % teacher) for teacher in teachers}
    delta_minus = {teacher : Int('d-_%s' % teacher) for teacher in teachers}
    DELTA = Real('DELTA')

    opt = Optimize()


    # constraint1: number of teachers needed per event
    num_available_per_event = {event : len(list(filter(lambda assignment: assignment[1] == event, possible_assignments))) for event in events}
    for event in events:
        num_teachers_to_assign = min(event_size[event], num_available_per_event[event])
        opt.add(Sum( [If(x[assignment], 1, 0) for assignment in x.keys() if assignment[1] == event] ) == num_teachers_to_assign)


    for teacher in teachers:
        
        # constraint2: max and min number of events for each teacher
        max_events = len(events)
        min_events = 0
        num_assigned_events = Sum( [If(x[assignment], 1, 0) for assignment in x.keys() if assignment[0] == teacher] )
        opt.add(num_assigned_events >= min_events, num_assigned_events <= max_events)

    
        # constraint3: teacher can't work in multiple overlapping events
        for overlapping_events in event_overlap_sets:
            opt.add(Sum( [If(x[assignment], 1, 0) for assignment in x.keys() if assignment[1] in overlapping_events and assignment[0] == teacher] ) <= 1)

        
        # constraint4: delta (absolute over and underload of teacher)
        num_teacher_workdays = Sum( [If(x[assignment], event_durations[assignment[1]], 0) for assignment in x.keys() if assignment[0] == teacher])
        opt.add(delta_plus[teacher] >= 0, delta_minus[teacher] >= 0)
        opt.add(delta_plus[teacher] - delta_minus[teacher] == num_teacher_workdays - desired_workdays[teacher])


        # constraint5: DELTA (maximum relative deviation of wished to assigned workdays)
        opt.add(DELTA >= ToReal(delta_plus[teacher] + delta_minus[teacher]) / desired_workdays[teacher])

    #opt.add(DELTA <= 1) # adding this results in better optimum

    average_rel_workday_deviation = Sum( [ToReal(delta_plus[teacher] + delta_minus[teacher]) / desired_workdays[teacher] for teacher in teachers]) / len(teachers)
    overall_distance = Sum( [If(x[assignment], assignment[3], 0) for assignment in x.keys()])
    num_prio2 = Sum( [If(x[assignment], assignment[2]-1, 0) for assignment in x.keys()])
    
    obj_fun = opt.minimize(
        a1 * average_rel_workday_deviation
        + a2 * DELTA
        + a3 * overall_distance
        + a4 * num_prio2
    )

    #print(opt)
    if opt.check() == sat:
        m = opt.model()

        optimal_assignments = []
        for assignment in x.keys():
            if m.evaluate(x[assignment]):
                optimal_assignments.append(assignment)

        for teacher in teachers:
            print(f"{teacher}: d+ {m.evaluate(delta_plus[teacher])}, d- {m.evaluate(delta_minus[teacher])}")
        #print(m)
        print("DELTA:::", m.evaluate(DELTA))
        print("min value:", obj_fun.value().as_decimal(2))

        return optimal_assignments

    else:
        print("Not satisfiable")
        return []


compute_optimum(1,1,1,1)
```

Sample input:

```py
teachers = ['fr', 'hö', 'pf', 'bo', 'jö', 'sti', 'bi', 'la', 'he', 'kl', 'sc', 'str', 'ko', 'ba'] 
events = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] 
event_overlap_sets = [{5, 6}, {8, 9}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}] 
desired_workdays = {'fr': 36, 'hö': 50, 'pf': 30, 'bo': 100, 'jö': 80, 'sti': 56, 'bi': 20, 'la': 140, 'he': 5.0, 'kl': 50, 'sc': 38, 'str': 42, 'ko': 20, 'ba': 20} 
event_size = {5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 3, 12: 2} 
event_durations = {5: 5.0, 6: 5.0, 7: 5.0, 8: 16, 9: 7.0, 10: 5.0, 11: 16, 12: 5.0} 

# assignment: (teacher, event, priority, distance)
possible_assignments = [('he', 5, 1, 11), ('sc', 5, 1, 48), ('str', 5, 1, 199), ('ko', 6, 1, 53), ('jö', 7, 1, 317), ('bo', 9, 1, 56), ('sc', 10, 1, 25), ('ba', 11, 1, 224), ('bo', 11, 1, 312), ('jö', 11, 1, 252), ('kl', 11, 1, 248), ('la', 11, 1, 303), ('pf', 11, 1, 273), ('str', 11, 1, 228), ('kl', 5, 2, 103), ('la', 5, 2, 16), ('pf', 5, 2, 48), ('bi', 6, 2, 179), ('la', 6, 2, 16), ('pf', 6, 2, 48), ('sc', 6, 2, 48), ('str', 6, 2, 199), ('sc', 7, 2, 354), ('sti', 7, 2, 314), ('bo', 8, 2, 298), ('fr', 8, 2, 375), ('hö', 9, 2, 95), ('jö', 9, 2, 119), ('sc', 9, 2, 37), ('sti', 9, 2, 95), ('bi', 10, 2, 211), ('hö', 11, 2, 273), ('bi', 12, 2, 408), ('bo', 12, 2, 318), ('ko', 12, 2, 295), ('la', 12, 2, 305), ('sc', 12, 2, 339), ('str', 12, 2, 218)]
```

Output (just the delta+ and delta-):

```
 ------- FINDING OPTIMUM TO WEIGHTS: a1=1, a2=1, a3=1, a4=1 -------

fr: d+ 17, d- 37
hö: d+ 26, d- 69
pf: d+ 0, d- 25
bo: d+ 41, d- 120
jö: d+ 0, d- 59
sti: d+ 27, d- 71
bi: d+ 0, d- 15
la: d+ 0, d- 119
he: d+ 0, d- 0
kl: d+ 0, d- 50
sc: d+ 0, d- 33
str: d+ 0, d- 32
ko: d+ 0, d- 20
ba: d+ 10, d- 14
DELTA::: 19/10
min value: 3331.95?
```

---

**What I observe that does not make sense to me**:

1. often, neither delta_plus nor delta_minus for a teacher equals 0, DELTA is bigger than 1
2. adding constraint 'DELTA <= 1' results in a smaller objective function value, faster computation and observation 1 cannot be observed anymore

*Also: the computation takes forever (although this is not the point of this)*

I am happy for any sort of help!

---

**Edit:**
Like suggested by alias, changing the delta+/- variables to `Real` and removing the two `ToReal()` statements yields the desired result. If you look at the generated expressions of my sample input, there are in fact slight differences (also besides the different datatype and missing `to_real` statements).

For example, when looking at the constraint, which is supposed to constrain that delta_plus - delta_minus of 'fri' is equals to 16 - 36 if he works for event 8, 0 - 36 if he doesn't.

*My old code using integers and ToReal-conversions produces this expression:*

```
(assert (= (- d+_fr d-_fr) (- (+ (ite e8_fr 16 0)) 36)))
```

*The code using Reals and no type-conversions produces this:*

```
(assert (let ((a!1 (to_real (- (+ (ite e8_fr 16 0)) 36))))
  (= (- d+_fr d-_fr) a!1)))
```

Also the minimization expressions are slightly different:

*My old code using integers and ToReal-conversions produces this expression:*

```
(minimize (let (
        (a!1 ...)
        (a!2 (...))
        (a!3 (...))
    )
    (+ (* 1.0 (/ a!1 14.0)) (* 1.0 DELTA) a!2 a!3)))
```

*The code using Reals and no type-conversions produces this:*

```
(minimize (let (
    (a!1 (/ ... 14.0))
    (a!2 (...))
    (a!3 (...))
  )
  (+ (* 1.0 a!1) (* 1.0 DELTA) a!2 a!3)))
```

Sadly I don't know really know how to read this but it seems quite the same to me.

Comment: You really need to provide a sample value for data where the computation goes awry for anyone else to be able to debug this. I suspect one of the calculations get truncated because you’re mixing integers/reals incorrectly. Can you provide a sample run with the actual data values?

Comment: Alright, ty for the feedback, I now provided an example. You should be able to simply copy/paste

Comment: Interesting; looks like mixing/matching integers/reals is throwing z3 off somehow. What happens if you make everything a real-value. (i.e., get rid of all the `Int`'s, and conversions using `ToReal`.) Do you get more consistent results then with the extra constraint?

Comment: Okay, like suggested I changed delta_plus and _minus to Real. Therefore I could remove all ToReal statements. **This does in fact seem to work!** Although this is a bit stupid as the deltas can only be Ints anyway and making them as Real increases computation time (which is critical for me).

Comment: Is there any other way in the Python API to declare a `/` instead of a `div` operation, than to make the operands `Real`s?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. But at the end of the day, we first need to figure out why there's a discrepancy. The way to do that would be to look at the output of both variants: insert a `print(opt.sexpr())` call right before you call `opt.check()`, and compare the output of both variants. Do the differences look reasonable? If not, this'd be a z3 bug that needs to be reported.

Comment: I looked at the expressions but I really don't know if it's reasonable. Please have a look at my edited initial question. What I meant is that in my case I only need the (apparently) problematic `ToReal()` statement to specify a division without rounding. I don't know if there's a way to specify this operation in the Python API without type casting.

Comment: See if you can reduce your problem as much as possible, and report it at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues to seek clarification on why the results are different. The smaller the instance you can get, the better chance the developers will have to fix the issue.